# The Curve Become Horny After Bevel

Tags: bezier-curves, bevel

I am trying to model a track for wheel using curve. But I get the bottom rail to have horns like this:
[image]

The orange curves are the reference used for beveling the linear curve as it is informed at the curve information bar on the right side.

How to make that bottom curve to behave like the top one?

Answer (score 1):

So I found that the problem was the origin of the curve (the square one) that is used for beveling is not in the center of beveling curve (the square curve).